# Error C2079: how can I handle this?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I try including my `player.h` in `battlefield.h` this error occurs:
`error C2079: 'BattleField::firstplayer' uses undefined class 'Player'.`
Can't really understand why is this happening, I've searched it through the net, and saw the circular pattern problem, but that's not very clear to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Player.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "classDeck.h"

class Player
{
private:

    char* Name;
    double Health;
    double Energy;

public:
    Deck playerdeck;

    Player();
    Player( char* Name, double Health, double Energy );
    Player( const Player& play );
    Player& operator= ( const Player & play );
    ~Player();

    void set_Name( char* Name );
    void set_Health( double val );
    void set_Energy( double val );
    void print_Player()const;

    char* get_Name()const
    {
        return Name;
    }

    double get_Health()const
    {
        return Health;
    }

    double get_Energy()const
    {
        return Energy;
    }



};

#endif
```

battleField.h:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

#ifndef BATTLEFIELD_H
#define BATTLEFIELD_H

#include "classDeck.h"
#include "Player.h"
class BattleField
{

private:

    Deck firstPlayer;    //TESTE NA PURVI IGRACH
    Deck secondPlayer;   //TESTE NA VTORI IGRACH
    Deck semetary;     //MASIV Grobishte

    Player firstplayer1;
    Player secondplayer2;

public:

    Deck playedCards; //MASIV OT IZIGRANI KARTI

    BattleField();  // PODRAZBIRASHT SE KONSTRUKTOR
    ~BattleField(); //DESTRUKTOR
    BattleField( const BattleField& battle ); // KOPIRASHT KONSTRUKTOR
    BattleField& operator= ( const BattleField& battle ); //OPERATOR =

    void insertLeftPlayDeck(const Deck& deck);  // ZADAVAME TESTE NA EDINIQ IGRACH
    void insertRightPlayDeck(const Deck& deck); //ZADAVAME TESTE NA DRUGIQ IGRACH

    void Battle(); //FUNKCIQ, V KOQTO DVE KARTI SE BIQT
    void display(); //PRINTIRASHTA FUNKCIQ
    void Serializer(); //SERIALIZIRASHTA
    const Deck get_semetary() const;
    const Deck get_playedCards()const;
    const Deck get_firstPlayer() const;
    const Deck get_secondPlayer() const;

};
#endif
```

Comment: Does `classDeck.h` include either of these 2 headers?

Comment: This is classDeck.h: http://pastebin.com/vF9Nyu56

Comment: Could you paste the error exactly as it appears? There is no `BattleField::firstplayer`, so it's hard to guess whether you mean `firstPlayer` or `firstplayer1`.

Comment: This is the exact error:  error C2079: 'BattleField::firstplayer' uses undefined class 'Player'.

Comment: @SuatHusein: That's weird, if true - there is no member called `firstplayer`. Which source line does it refer to?

Comment: where the Player firstplayer1 is..

Comment: It's a circular include. You didn't answer if classDeck.h includes these 2 files even indirectly.

Comment: That error message comes with a line number and source text. Add those to the question **verbatim**.

Comment: battlefield.h(18): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int this error appears usually, but now this one: battlefield.h(18): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'firstplayer1'. Luchian, I included them indirectly, now as I see, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @SuatHusein _'what can I do to fix it?'_ You can use forward declarations, instead of including the headers from other headers. When you need a particular class for the declaration of another class just say e.g. `class Player;` before using a pointer or reference in your declarations. Do the corresponding `#include "Player.h"`only in the implementation file of the other class declared.